# Swift - Wrap a website into an Ios app?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm quite new to swift & IOS development.

Is it possible to create an app in swift that will run a website inside of the app?

If so could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add UIWebView component or WKWebView component - tutorial can be found here: http://www.kinderas.com/technology/2014/6/7/getting-started-with-wkwebview-using-swift-in-ios-8

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but it is going to be rejected by Apple in all probability unless you provide some more functionality, i.e., don't **JUST** wrap a website in an app and submit it.

Having said that, all you need to do is use an instance of UIWebView in your app and set the URL to load your website in `viewDidLoad` function

So your `viewDidLoad` function would look something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.apple.com")
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    self.webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```